# Create conditions in http post for Android application

Tags: android, button, http-post

I want each button created to send a different namevaluepairs data to the server. I tried switch case method in try{..} which was unsuccessful because the buttons are not strings.

**Main.java**

```
public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private Button cnfrm;
private Button absnt;
private Button ntfy;
private ProgressBar pb;
//private ProgressBar pb_absnt;
//private ProgressBar pb_ntfy;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
cnfrm =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
absnt =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
ntfy =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
pb=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
cnfrm.setOnClickListener(this);
//pb_absnt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
absnt.setOnClickListener(this);
//pb_ntfy.setVisibility(View.GONE);
ntfy.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.button1 :
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        new MyAsyncTask().execute(toString());  
        break;
    case R.id.button2 :
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        new MyAsyncTask().execute(toString());  
        break;
    case R.id.button3 :
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        new MyAsyncTask().execute(toString());  
    break;

    }

}

private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>{

@Override
protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    postData(params[0]);
return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Double result){
    pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "command sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
    pb.setProgress(progress[0]);

}

public void postData(String valueIWantToSend) {
// Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://172.20.154.8:8080/Server/LoginJ");

//v cannot be resolved, onClick cannot be resolved
switch (v.getId()) {
case R.id.button1 : 
try {
    // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Restaurant ID","0002"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UserID","6585001342"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("checkin",Integer.toString(1)));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("absent",Integer.toString(0)));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("notify",Integer.toString(0)));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        /*case R.id.button2 :

            break;
        case R.id.button3 :

            break;*/

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
    break;
case R.id.button2 :
    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Restaurant ID","0002"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UserID","6585001342"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("checkin",Integer.toString(0)));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("absent",Integer.toString(1)));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("notify",Integer.toString(0)));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
        break;
case R.id.button3 :
    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Restaurant ID","0002"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UserID","6585001342"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("checkin",Integer.toString(0)));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("absent",Integer.toString(0)));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("notify",Integer.toString(1)));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
        break;
    }
}

}

}
```

**Main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="42dp"
    android:text="Submit" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
    android:text="Absent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="65dp"
    android:text="Notify" />


<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="58dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android_post_request"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="20" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

I couldn't get switch(v.getId()) to work for postData function

Answer (score 0):

You're sending the toString() of the Activity to the AsyncTask as a parameter. In your onClick method try passing v.getId() instead:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.button1 :
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        new MyAsyncTask().execute(v.getId());  
        break;
    case R.id.button2 :
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        new MyAsyncTask().execute(v.getId());  
        break;
    case R.id.button3 :
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        new MyAsyncTask().execute(v.getId());  
    break;

    }

}
```

This way you can use your switch/case to send different name/value pairs in the AsyncTask.

Comment: `execute(v.getId()); ` did not work for me. It suggested to use onPostexecute instead, but error still occurred.